# HomePod mini fails setup: "Wi-Fi Incompatible"

Tags: wifi, homepod

I am trying to setup my new HomePod mini.

After getting through all the questions, and holding my iPhone camera over the swirling pixels, I get an error message:

> Wi-Fi Incompatible
>
> The current Wi-Fi network from this iPhone cannot be used to set up your HomePod.

I tried switching between the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz versions of my wifi router. The router sits about 5 feet away, with clear line-of-sight.

- I tried "forget my network" several times, and rejoining the wifi after re-entering wifi password.
- I tried turning off the MAC address spoofing feature that Apple enables by default, *Private Wi-Fi Address*.

I tried using another 2.4 GHz wifi router, in another room. Same error message.

Anything else for me to try before returning this HomePod mini to the store?

Comment: Try this, when you switch to 2.4Ghz change your WiFi network name. Then connect your phone to that new WiFi network and try connecting the HomePod mini.  From my past experience, IoT devices mostly only work in 2.4Ghz.

Comment: @JashJacob Apple’s [tech specs](https://www.apple.com/homepod-mini/specs/) page says HomePod mini supports [802.11n Wi-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009) which includes both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. And anyways, I did try both 2.4 & 5 GHz on one router, and 2.4 on another.

Comment: You should call Apple to ensure they don't have a document describing what these requirements are. Anyways, I checked and my HomePod mini is connected via 5G

Comment: I did finally get my HomePod mini to work. But I do not know how exactly, because I tried so many things that day. Eventually I did contact Apple Support via chat. They had me start from scratch, powering everything on and off, and then waiting on the mini until it *after* it (a) made swirling ball of white light going round and round, then (b) went black, and then finally (c) showed a centered pulsating white light along with a deep chime. Only after that point did I unlock the iPhone to press the "Set up" button offered by the HomePod mini dialog appearing on my iPhone. This somehow worked.